# replace characters after occurrence of a specific character in R

Tags: r

I have a list of characters like this:-

```
a <- c("NM020506_1","NM_020519_1","NM00_1030297.2")
```

I am trying to get an output like this using base R.

```
NM020506, NM, NM00
```

i.e ignore everything after "_".

I tried something like this. But clearly it is not correct.

```
a
[1] "NM020506_1"     "NM_020519_1"    "NM00_1030297.2"
> substr(a,1,unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='_',a))-1)
[1] "NM020506"  "NM"        "NM00_1030"
>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sub` function, whereby you substitute everything after _ with empty.

```
a <- c("NM020506_1","NM_020519_1","NM00_1030297.2")
sub("_.*","",a)
[1] "NM020506" "NM"       "NM00"
```

No need to use `gregexpr` since it is greedy and yet you only need the first `-` . You can rather use `regexpr` which is not greedy

```
substr(a,1,regexpr(pattern ='_',a)-1)
[1] "NM020506" "NM"       "NM00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit`as:

```
#data 
a <- c("NM020506_1","NM_020519_1","NM00_1030297.2")

sapply(strsplit(a,"_"),function(x)x[1])

#[1] "NM020506" "NM"       "NM00"
```